# Cloud Firestore Security Rules for array operations

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to restrict certain operations towards Firestore to creating or appending to an array. How should I do that? How can I distinguish `arrayUnion()` from `arrayDelete()`? What about distinguishing array operations from all the other operations?

**Update**: So far, from what I got by digging into the Firestore API, I'm guessing maybe something like `allow create, FieldValue.arrayUnion: if true` could work, but I haven't tested it yet, will update when I tested it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to ensure that any updates to the document don't remove any f the existing values from the array, you're looking for [`hasAll`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAll):

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.arrayField.hasAll(resource.data.arrayField);
```

I just quickly tested this in the simulator. Updating a document that has `arrayField: ["value1", "value2"]`, I:

- Failed when writing `arrayField: ["value1"]`
- Succeeded when writing `arrayField: ["value1", "value2"]`
- Succeeded when writing `arrayField: ["value1", "value2", "value3"]`

Comment: This seems like a valid approach, however, on my client side, I'm updating the array without including the entire array (I'm using the `.update("regions", FieldValue.arrayUnion("value_to_append"))` method), are you sure when I call the method, the request will have all the elements in the array? I couldn't test it right away because my whole set up is rather complicated.

Comment: Yup. `request.resource` is the document as it will exist after the write operation (if that is permitted). If that doesn't work in your testing, post back with what you've tried.

Comment: Cool! I'll give this a shot asap.